# UI5: Validate Whole Form's Required and Visible Fields for Null/Blank Values

Tags: forms, validation, input, combobox, sapui5

onPress of submit button, I want to validate all SimpleForms' fields (ComboBox, Input, DatePicker, etc.) that are

1. required &
2. visible

to see if they are null or blank (""). If a targeted (required & visible) field is null/blank, set that control's state to "Error" and display an error message. If no targeted field is null/blank, pop up a success dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is automated so in the future, any fields added later will automatically be checked without need of manual additions to controller code.

**Controller code**:

```js
requiredAndVisible: function(oControl) {
    if (typeof oControl.getRequired === "function") { //certain ctrls like toolbars dont have getRequired as a method, so we want to skim those out, else itll throw an error later in the next check
      if (oControl.getRequired() === true && oControl.getVisible() === true) {
        return oControl;
      }
    }
  },

  onSubmit: function() {
    var valid = true,
      oView = this.getView(),
      aFormInitial = oView.byId("formInitial").getContent(), // get all the controls of SimpleForm1
      aFormConfig = oView.byId("formConfiguration").getContent(), // get all controls of SimpleForm2
      aControls = aFormInitial.concat(aFormConfig), // combine the 2arrays together into 1
      aFilteredControls = aControls.filter(this.requiredAndVisible); // check each element if it required & visible using the 1st function. return only the controls that are both req'd & visible

    aFilteredControls.forEach(function(oControl) { // in resultant array, check each element if...  
      if (!oControl.getValue() || oControl.getValue().length < 1) { // its value is null or blank
        oControl.setValueState("Error");
        valid = false; // set valid to false if it is
      } else {
        oControl.setValueState("None");
      }
    });

    if (valid === false) {
      // **replace this code with w/e error handling code u want**
      oView.byId("errorMsgStrip").setVisible(true);
    } else if (valid === true) {
      // **replace this code with whatever success handling code u want**
      var oDialogConfirm = new sap.ui.xmlfragment("dialogID", "dialog.address.here", this);
      oDialogConfirm.open();
    }
  },
```

Comment: I think it's great that you answered your own question immediately (like some kind of tutorial) but imo this code can be heavily optimized.

Comment: optimizations are always welcome. id love to see how it can be morphed into something better that our community can use